# Create SqlParameter with name and type only (no value assigned)

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, sqlclient, sqlparameter

I am having issue to use SqlClient to call some sql query with parameter declared but not assigned. The query I want to run is similar to below

```
DECLARE @ID int;
SELECT @ID = OrderId
FROM Orders
ORDER BY OrderId DESC;
SELECT @ID;
```

However, when I created SqlParameter as following

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("ID", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

I got error showing:

> "The parameterized query
> '(@ID int)SELECT @ID = OrderId
> FROM Orders
> ORDER BY OrderId DES'
> expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied."

Any suggestions on how to create SqlParameter without any value assigned in such case?

Comment: If you are trying to use null you need to add the parameter with a value of `DBNull.Value`. If the stored procedure expects a value for the `@ID` field then you are required to provide one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to specify that @ID is an output parameter.

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("ID", SqlDbType.Int)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
}
```

When the query will be executed you can retrieve that value via

```
parameter.Value
```

It will return an instance of the object type.

Comment: I thought parameter direction only matters for stored procedure output parameter. did not know anything to return in the parameter needs to be specified as Output. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First things first, it doesn't appear your query will return a single int, but many result rows that each contain an `OrderId`. You are selecting OrderId from every row in the table and trying to assign it to a single int variable - this won't work. If you just want the greatest OrderId, you can try `SELECT TOP 1 @ID = OrderId` as seen below.

To answer the question, the other answers are correct that you need to specify the parameter direction as output. [Output parameters](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/) are different than input parameters.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    @id = OrderId
FROM 
    Orders
ORDER BY 
    OrderId DESC;
```

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure to use output variables.